# Error when installing alignlib-lite with pip install

Tags: python, linux, bash, pip

Iam trying to install a python package but I get an error that I could not find a solution. Can somebody help me? 
Here is the error menssage:

```
tiago@tiago:~/Rscripts$ sudo pip install alignlib-lite
The directory '/home/tiago/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is      not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/tiago/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not     owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
    Collecting alignlib-lite
  Downloading alignlib-lite-0.2.3.tar.gz (226kB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 229kB 393kB/s 
Installing collected packages: alignlib-lite
  Running setup.py install for alignlib-lite ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-3Y6mrr/alignlib-lite/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-b6OHJX-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/extension.py:133: UserWarning: Unknown Extension options: 'cmdclass'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running install
running build
running build_ext
cythoning alignlib_lite.pyx to alignlib_lite.cpp
building 'alignlib_lite' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/alignlib_src
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Ialignlib_src -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c alignlib_lite.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/alignlib_lite.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
alignlib_lite.cpp:256:32: fatal error: boost/shared_ptr.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

     ----------------------------------------
 Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-3Y6mrr/alignlib-lite/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-b6OHJX-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-3Y6mrr/alignlib-lite
```

Comment: "fatal error: boost/shared_ptr.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated." That means you likely don't have (the development version of) the boost library installed. Use your package manager to install boost (or boost-dev, or boost-devel, whatever comes up for your system).

Comment: If you run into such compiler issues more often when installing Python packages with pip, you may want to look into `conda` instead. I've never used it (I just install the C dependencies separately), but I understand it's a Python package manager that can also take care of C library dependencies, not just the Python side.

Comment: indeed, after installing boost library I could install alignlib-lite. Thanks